# Is Twilio recording audio during the wrap up phase, after a call is finished?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

after an agent takes a call in Twilio and ends a call, the call goes into a wrap up phase.  During this wrap up phase, before you hit complete, is Twilio recording any audio?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I assume you are asking about Flex here, which is the only part of Twilio that has a wrap up phase.

In Flex, when you hang up a call the task goes into the wrap up stage. At this point there is not a live call, so, even if you were recording the call while it was taking place, the wrap up phase is not recorded because there is no live call at this stage.

Comment: Thanks so much Phil!

Comment: No problem! If this does successfully answer your question, please do mark it as correct so that others can see it helped too. Thanks!